# Changing viewmodel

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp, xbind

I have simplified app to show my issue

When I click button, it changes `Text` property of `ViewModel` and `TextBlock.Text` is updated.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<StackPanel>
  <Button  Click="ButtonBase_OnClick">Button to change text</Button>
  <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Text, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel.Text = "x:Bind works";
    }
```

**ViewModel** class has one string property (Text) and implemented *INotifyPropertyChange* interface.

---

Problem starts when `ViewModel` is not set in ctor (i.e. viewModel is null and changed in runtime):

```
   public MainPage()
    {
        //ViewModel = new ViewModel();//this line has been removed
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
 private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();//this line has been added
        ViewModel.Text = "x:Bind does not work";
    }
```

---

Complited **binding is not working** (Text is not changed) and I could not figure out why it is so... I need to change viewModel from null (vm is null because it is waiting for some data in real app)

Comment: Of course, because there is no notification that ViewModel has changed

Comment: You mean ViewModel property? How can I notify about change - I dont want to implement INotifyPropertychange in MainPage

Comment: Without magic you had to notify the page that the content of ViewModel has changed. It does not matter how you do it but you have to

Comment: Maybe you should use DataContext property - there is already a built in event DataContextChanged and the binding system is aware of this

Comment: Without having INotifyPropertyChange implement you are going to have to do a lot more than set a property in a poco if you want the item to be bound successfully. If you are new to xaml and bindings I would have a research on how MVVM works and you will fix the issue.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh848246.aspx

Comment: @Oli Ok, than.. It just didnt seem right to me to implement INotifyPropertyChenged in Page class...

Answer (score 2):

**{x:Bind}** bindings (often referred-to as compiled bindings) uses generated code to achieve its benefits. At XAML load time, **{x:Bind}** is converted into what you can think of as a binding object, and this object gets a value from a property on a data source. These generated code can be found in your ***`obj`*** folder, with names like (for C#) ***`<view name>.g.cs`***.

For your code, the generated code will like following:

```
// Update methods for each path node used in binding steps.
private void Update_(global::UWP.BlankPage3 obj, int phase)
{
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if ((phase & (NOT_PHASED | DATA_CHANGED | (1 << 0))) != 0)
        {
            this.Update_ViewModel(obj.ViewModel, phase);
        }
    }
}
private void Update_ViewModel(global::UWP.ViewModel obj, int phase)
{
    this.bindingsTracking.UpdateChildListeners_ViewModel(obj);
    if (obj != null)
    {
        if ((phase & (NOT_PHASED | DATA_CHANGED | (1 << 0))) != 0)
        {
            this.Update_ViewModel_Text(obj.Text, phase);
        }
    }
}

...

private global::UWP.ViewModel cache_ViewModel = null;
public void UpdateChildListeners_ViewModel(global::UWP.ViewModel obj)
{
    if (obj != cache_ViewModel)
    {
        if (cache_ViewModel != null)
        {
            ((global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged)cache_ViewModel).PropertyChanged -= PropertyChanged_ViewModel;
            cache_ViewModel = null;
        }
        if (obj != null)
        {
            cache_ViewModel = obj;
            ((global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged)obj).PropertyChanged += PropertyChanged_ViewModel;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I just copy some method that related to your issue. From these method, you can find that before update `TextBlock` or `PropertyChanged` listeners, it will check if the `ViewModel` is `null`. If it is `null`, nothing will be done. So to make **{x:Bind}** work, we must initialize `ViewModel` before page loaded. And this is the reason why **{x:Bind}** doesn't work when you initialize `ViewModel` in `Button.Click` event.

To fix this issue, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for `ViewModel` like Filip said so that the generated code can be notified when `ViewModel` changed (from `null` to `new ViewModel()`) and update you UI.

But I think you can just initialize `ViewModel` in constructor. When you initialize `ViewModel`, you can set the properties that you are waiting for to `null` first like:

```
public MainPage()
{
    ViewModel = new ViewModel() { Text = null };
    this.InitializeComponent();
}
```

And then update these properties when your date is ready. In this way, you can do not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your page.

Besides these, there is another cheaper way, you can call `this.Bindings.Update();` method to force the bindings to be updated after you initialize `ViewModel` like following:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ViewModel = new ViewModel();
    ViewModel.Text = "x:Bind does not work";
    this.Bindings.Update();
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but thank you so much. I didn't know about this.Bindings.Update().

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` on page like so

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ViewModel viewModel;

    public ViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get { return viewModel; }
        set 
        {
            viewModel = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ViewModel)));
        }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel { };
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel {  };//this line has been added
        ViewModel.Text = "x:Bind does not work";
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This works for me.